# What kinds of edits do we have?

Tags: discussion, support, editing

I'm kinda new here, but I already edit posts I think need it. 
I already edit posts for

- Grammar
- Spelling

and

- Math (I edit math to put it into LaTeX/MathJax format quite a lot, more often than any other edit type)

Are there any other edits I should know about? Any other edits that can be done? I often skim questions and answers simply for math and spelling--if I see math in a non-LaTeX format or with lots of spelling errors I edit it. But are there any more important/lesser known things I should edit, or things that can be added to a question/answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're editing a post anyway, scan the comments on it for anything from the author of the post that should be incorporated.  A common situation, especially with new users (who don't know all our rules yet), is that somebody will ask a question in a comment and the author will answer *in another comment* instead of by editing the post.  Not all such comments *need* to be in the post (sometimes that first commenter missed something, or it was a tangent), but if you see something that should be pulled in, please do so and then flag relevant comments as no longer needed.

Thank you for helping to maintain the site.

Answer (score 4):

Edits should make a post clearer, cleaner and in general more understandable. Edits should not change the intended meaning of a post. A comprehensive list of every possible edit isn't really possible, and isn't really useful. If you don't notice something that could be edited, it's likely someone else will. If you're unsure about an edit, add a comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can edit the tags used by the question if you feel they are not suited for the question but there is a part of subjectivity in deciding which tags are the best. It is also better to edit something else along if possible, not just the tags.

Answer (score 2):

Be reasonable in deciding if an edit should be made. Some errors are intentional. I try to avoid edits where the only edit is to correct one or two typo's.

I personally try make an edit if it will make the post clearer and easier to read, not on personal choice on how it should be formatted etc.

These are not rules. These are my personal editing preferences for when I make an edit myself. I try make edits that wouldn't annoy the OP. **Be nice**.

Add paragraph breaks to break up *long* walls of text. Make the actual question **obvious**. If it's a short question, this isn't strictly necessary. But I have been guilty of doing it (I then try at least incorporate *several* spelling and grammer corrections at the same time).

If a paragraph of criteria is a confusing jumble of criteria/rules and examples, sometimes with brackets within brackets etc, I consider adding bullet lists with the examples indented underneath the criteria/rules. Trying to keep the same sentence structure that the OP used.

Edits shouldn't change the spelling from American English to English English. Let the OP write color/colour as they choose. Obviously if there is a mix of spelling styles in the same question, then we can fix so that it is uniformly American/English all the way through.

Don't correct spelling mistakes and errors that are obviously intentional, unless it *really* detracts from the question. Eg puns.

If the post is only a few hours old and the OP clearly states they will edit later, either in the post or comments, and it's only a few errors, I try wait them out. Unless it is something really distracting like absolutely no paragraphs breaks or you need to make the question sentence really obvious :). They may have already noticed the typos/mistakes and they often will clear them up themselves when they add clarifications to focus the question. Especially if it's a typo that can be attributed to autocorrect. If they have already edited, and there are still errors, go for it.

When editing Headings, try stick with what the OP had written. I try leave headings alone as much as possible but occasionally a larger Heading edit is warranted.

If someone rolls back an edit, don't make the same edit suggestion again :)

If someone makes an edit on *your* post/answer that you don't agree with, simply rollback. They should understand. If the edited post does actually make the post easier to read in some way, rollback what you don't agree with and add any positive changes yourself.

Comment: +1 for making the question obvious, I often have to read through a huge block of text to find out what the OP actually wants. In these cases I usually **bold the question**

Answer (score 2):

What I missed in the other answers:

1. Remove unnecessary text. That happens less here than on other SE sites, because  some amount of sketching the environment/situation can be helpful. Still, phrases like *I'm looking for an answer to the question...*, *I have been thinking about...* can usually be stripped out.
   And of course there are the common phrases like *Thank you*, *What do you think* at the end of the question.
2. [Remove tags in titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)